# Placing icon inside PHP code on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to place a custom section in the Astra Wordpress Theme's header under a specific condition, with **Custom Layouts** feature, but I couldn't manage it properly. The thing is, I wanted to place the location of the featured header images in the header section with a custom icon. The thing is, I'm using the "caption" section of the Wordpress image. I can display only the caption section if it's not empty. My PHP knowledge is not perfect, but I've done the research and found nothing.

[Example: top right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujino.png)

I could display the caption section of the image but couldn't place the icon before the caption text.

I've tried many combinations, but still nothing.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
<div class="featured-image-caption-for-header"
    style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 10px; text-align: right; font-size: 12px; color: #3A4115;">
    <?php $featured_image_caption = the_post_thumbnail_caption(); if( $featured_image_caption ): ?>
    <i class="uil uil-camera"> </i>
    <?php echo esc_url( $featured_image_caption ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

My main goal is to display the icon before the caption text only when the caption section of the image is filled.

Comment: Your code snippet works fine. Is the issue in your live site that the icon isn't added to the HTML, that it is added to HTML but doesn't appear in the desired location, or something else?

Comment: @wouch I'm not sure. With the snippet I've shared, the icon is not visible at all. But it becomes visible If I place <i class="uil uil-camera"> </i> code before the first <?php. Then it also becomes visible even if the_post_thumbnail_caption section is empty which I don't want it to be happen that way.

Answer (score 0):

Placing `<i class="uil uil-camera"></i>` code before the caption text in Wordpress' photo editor displays the icon but this is what I really wanted. Still working on a better solution.

[Photo Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tpNg.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65jaD.png)